# GET the first result in HTTP request

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, ethernet

I have a `String content=""` and if I put an HTTP request like this:

```
client.println("GET /api/actions?parking_id=39 HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: ramp-rampcontrol.rhcloud.com");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();
```

the output I get is:

```
 [{"action_id":35,"action_type":"up","parking_id":39,"user_id":17,"ramp":"exit","created_at":"2015-07-10 18:02:40","updated_at":"2015-07-10 18:02:40"},{"action_id":41,"action_type":"up","parking_id":39,"user_id":17,"ramp":"entry","created_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:14","updated_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:14"},{"action_id":42,"action_type":"down","parking_id":39,"user_id":17,"ramp":"entry","created_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:21","updated_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:21"},{"action_id":43,"action_type":"down","parking_id":39,"user_id":17,"ramp":"exit","created_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:22","updated_at":"2015-08-16 20:50:22"}]
```

The little parser I created is this:

```
while(client.available()) {
 char c = client.read();   
    if(c == '{'){
      begin1 = true;
    }

  if (begin1) { 
    content += c;
   }

  if (c == '}') {
      break; 
    }
 }
```

Is it possible to store only the first action in JSON output, because the actions are updated, and if the number of chars extends 256 than I get errors while working with the `String content`?

Comment: `if (c == ',') {
      break; 
    }` (i.e. break on the first comma, instead of the first closing bracket)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear to me. First of all does your parser get the whole response? And second by first action do you mean "action_id":35"?
If both are true then your solution is simple.

First you separate every comma ", " and put in a string array then you further split each index by ":" so the first part is the name "action_id" and the second is the value "35". I hope that helps . You can look up the split function, it's easy.

But if the above is not what you needed then I am afraid you *cannot* get only the first response, because that has to do with the server itself.

Here is a solution, do try it.

I found an [easier solution](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson). Follow the example and replace the content and fields with your response content and you will be done in minutes.

Comment: Yes, the parser gets the whole response. I need only the first one stored in String content which in this example is :

[{"action_id":35,"action_type":"up","parking_id":39,"user_id":17,"ramp":"exit","created_at":"2015-07-10 18:02:40","updated_at":"2015-07-10 18:02:40"}

Comment: Darkclaude X, please edit your answer and adjust the unconventional, hard-to-read capitalization.  Capitalize the first word of each sentence; capitalize proper nouns and the pronoun *I*; don't capitalize other words.  Also, please spellcheck  “Seperate”.

Comment: thx Jwpat, FunKction check the library above

Comment: `Your question is not clear to me.` Getting clarification on questions belongs in the comments, not in an answer. Please adjust your answer and comment accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant comment on his Post i need 50 points